# What distance measure does centroid based meanshift algorithm uses for clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, mean-shift

I have a sparse TruncatedSVD matrices with 810 * 74 dimensions.  I am trying to cluster with centroid-based MeanShift algorithm using sklearn api.  However, I could not find information about the distance measure that meanshift uses by default neither in sklearn documentation nor in online blogs.  There is no option to provide a precomputed distance matrices too.  Does Meanshift caluculates Euclidean distance by default before doing centroid based computation?

Gone through sklearn documentation - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html

Also searched online but without a luck

Answer (score 0):

It's not using distances directly.

It's using the **RBF kernel**, which does however contain something akin to Euclidean distance inside.

I doubt this is a good choice for 74 dimensional data.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Do you suggest any other algorithm for 74 dimensions?  Data is sparse too.

Comment: Depends on your data, so I cannot give you recommendations. With this n and p, I'd say tough luck to get anything sound working.